# Find 10 nearest points

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, geospatial, geojson

I'm wondering how I can search for 10 closest points to my location. Currently I'm having something like this:

```
  const query50 = Event.where('location').near({
        center: {
            type: 'Point',
            coordinates: [data.lng, data.lat]
        },
        maxDistance: 50000,
        spherical: true
    });
```

but this allows me to show all events in 50km radius. Now I would love to fetch 10 closest to me but without setting *maxDistance*. Is there some **efficent** way to do that?

Comment: you'll have to calculate distance using `Math.sqrt( Math.pow(lat_diff, 2) + Math.pow(long_diff, 2) );` and find shortest distances. You technically wouldn't need to calculate the sqrt part if you're just looking for the shortest distances.

Comment: sort the results and set limit to 10.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no. But you car sort your result by the distance to your location, its fairly fast.

Comment: and what about
`const closest10 = Event.where('location').near({
        center: {
            type: 'Point',
            coordinates: [data.long, data.lat]
        },
        spherical: true
    }).limit(10);`  wouldn't that solve a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Limit using `.limit(n)` method

```
db.places
  .find({
     location:
       { 
          $near: {
              $geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [-73.9667, 40.78] }
          }
       }
   })
    .limit(10)
    .exec(function(err, result) { /*...*/ });
```

`$maxDistance` and `$minDistance` are optional

[Example of using `$near` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/near/#examples)